# Configuración de apache

Tags: apache, amazon

Actualmente tenemos un certificado comprado para X dominio, al momento de configurara un subdominio e instalar el certificado todo funciona correctamente, pero este subdominio apunta a otra ip (servidor de amazon), cuando realizo la configuración de apache en el servidor de amazon, ¿Tendría que configurar mi apache con los archivos de certificación comprado o las llaves que se generar en WHM?

Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Los certificados ssl van ligados al dominio si el dominio apunta a "X"  ip donde esta tu sevidor "apache" hay debes configurarlo ya que el domain es solo un  alias para una ip y lo unico que hace tu provedoor es redirigir

Answer (score 0):

Debes alojar los certificados en el servidor apache y indicarle la ruta de la ubicacion algo como esto

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html2
ServerName su.dominio.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /ruta/a/su_dominio.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /ruta/a/su_dominio.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /ruta/a/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Algunos certificados Lets Encrypt son solo validos para ser usados en el mismo servidor en donde esta el apache, con lo cual es posible tengas que comprar a un tercero el certificado.